# Register advice globally for each .handle() method in all Integrationflows

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Is there a way to do this:

```
                            .handle(Http.outboundGateway(host + url)
                                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                                    .mappedRequestHeaders("contentType", "x-api-key")
                                    .expectedResponseType(String.class), e -> e.advice(expressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice))
```

where the advice is registered globally somewhere so you don't have to register it in each call?

There are a lot of http outbound gateways in the project to which I need to apply/register the same advice and was wondering if I have to do it manually for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

No; there is currently no concept of a "global" advice that can be (conditionally) applied to multiple endpoints.

Feel free to open a new feature suggestion [on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues) and contributions are welcome.

Comment: You can have an `e -> e.advice(expressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice)` as a standalone object and reuse it in all the HTTP gateways you need to apply it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your statement. I do have a bean of type ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice defined in a configuration class.